# jquery background-image swicher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Html

```
<aside> 
 // Floats to the right
</aside> 
<div class="backimage" > 
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var i = 0;
 var total = $('#total').val();
 var image = $('.backimage');
 var images = [];
 for(i = 0; i<total; i++)
 {
  images[i] = $('#image'+i+'').val();
 }
 image.css('background-image', 'url('+images[images.length-1]+')');
 image.css('background-size', '930px 500px');
 image.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
 setInterval(function(){
 image.fadeOut(1000, function(){
  image.css('background-image', 'url('+images[i++]+')');
  image.fadeIn(1000);
 });
 if(i == images.length)
   i = 0;
 }, 5000);

 });
```

Suppose to be a simple background-image switcher but the problem is that when the background-image fadein the backimage div appears in front of the floating aside before going behind it
Could probably do it with an img tag but feel that will make the load time slower, really need helper before considering the alternatives

Comment: Make a fiddle of your code.

Comment: `img` tag slower than `background-image`? They both need to be loaded so probably the same slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally needs a jsfiddle to see the issue, but my guess is that you just need to put a div outside the backimage, and set a width and height on this.

When jquery's fadeout reaches 0, the display style is set to none.  My guess would be this is when your layout breaks.